# How to use html5 to develop a video and audio call social application without using webrtc so that it is supported on all browsers?

Tags: html, html5-video, webrtc, html5-audio, getusermedia

How to use html5 to develop a video and audio call social application without using webrtc so that it is supported on all browsers?

I've tried webrtc however it doesn't work on IE or ios.

Thankyou

Comment: As soon as you invent some other technology that can do that and implement it in all browsers… or you deal with reality and face the fact that WebRTC is the best we've got, **even though it's not yet supported on all browsers** (but we're slowly but surely getting there).

Comment: So how did viber develop such cross platform application

Comment: Is Viber using HTML 5? Last I know of them they were writing native apps.

Comment: Do you know anything about how viber developed a native application with video and voice chat? Kind Regards

Answer (score 3):

You want to

> Use HTML5

(and presumably javascript) to

> develop video and audio call application

and

> without using webrtc

**You can't. No such thing exists.**